# Balanced trees and space and time trade-offs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I was trying to solve problem 3-1 for large input sizes given in the following link http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps3_sol.pdf. The solution uses an AVL tree for range queries and that got me thinking.

I was wondering about scalability issues when the input size increases from a million to a billion and beyond. For instance consider a stream of integers (size: 4 bytes) and input of size 1 billion, the space required to store the integers in memory  would be ~3GB!! The problem gets worse when you consider other data types such as floats and strings with the input size the order of magnitude under consideration.

Thus, I reached the conclusion that I would require the assistance of secondary storage to store all those numbers and pointers to child nodes of the AVL tree. I was considering storing the left and right child nodes as separate files but then I realized that that would be too many files and opening and closing the files would require expensive system calls and time consuming disk access and thus at this point I realized that AVL trees would not work.

I next thought about B-Trees and the advantage they provide as each node can have 'n' children, thereby reducing the number of files on disk and at the same time packing in more keys at every level. I am considering creating separate files for the nodes and inserting the keys in the files as and when they are generated.

1) I wanted to ask if my approach and thought-process is correct and
2) Whether I am using the right data structure and if B-Trees are the right data structure what should the order be to make the application efficient? What flavour of B Trees would yield maximum efficiency. Sorry for the long post! Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're reasoning is correct, although there are probably smarter schemes than to store one node per file. In fact, a B(+)-Tree often outperforms a binary search tree in practice (especially for very large collections) for numerous reasons and that's why just about every major database system uses it as its main index structure. Some reasons why binary search trees don't perform too well are:

1. Relatively large tree height (1 billion elements ~ height of 30 (if perfectly balanced)).
2. Every comparison is completely unpredictable (50/50 choice), so the hardware can't pre-fetch memory and fill the cpu pipeline with instructions.
3. After the upper few levels, you jump far away and to unpredictable locations in memory, each possibly requiring accessing the hard drive.

A B(+)-Tree with a high order will always be relatively shallow (height of 3-5) which reduces number of disk accesses. For range queries, you can read consecutively from memory while in binary trees you jump around a lot. Searching in a node may take a bit longer, but practically speaking you are limited by memory accesses not CPU time anyway.

So, the question remains what order to use? Usually, the node size is chosen to be equal to the page size (4-64KB) as optimizing for disk accesses is paramount. The page size is the minimal consecutive chunk of memory your computer may load from disk to main memory. Depending on the size of your key, this will result in a different number of elements per node.

For some help for the implementation, just look at how B+-Trees are implemented in database systems.

Comment: Nice summary! A fully balanced BST of height 20 holds only a million elements, though, not 10^9, and it's even less for real BSTs with their relaxed balance criteria (i.e. AVL, Red-Black). The worst sin of BSTs is poor use of CPU caches - they hit a new cache line with every comparison (child link deref), whereas B+trees can squeeze the maximum amount of comparisons out of each cache line, with a bit of care. The divergence gets even greater when secondary storage is involved.

Comment: In fact, the performance of BSTs is so poor that they are never a good choice if performance matters. Hash containers beat them to pulp in memory, and as sorted containers go they are outperformed by sorted vectors at the low end and B-trees (or B+trees) everywhere else. The niche for BSTs is applications where their underwhelming performance doesn't matter and the engineering for a performant solution cannot be justified.

Comment: Right, 2^30 is about billion, not 2^20. I edited this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replies! I understood why B+ trees are used for scalability. I wanted to know how B+ Trees are indexed and if I would have to write a program, in what ways I could store the B+ Tree on disk if my scheme of one file per node is a bit slower! Many thanks!!